# How to select item in dx-treeview use AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, treeview, devextreme

I trying Select item in *dx-tree-view*, my treeview config:

```
$scope.treeViewOptions = {
        bindingOptions: {
            dataSource: 'localArray',
            searchValue: "searchValue",
        },
        keyExpr: 'id',
        displayExpr: 'caption',
        parentIdExpr: 'parentId',
        dataStructure: 'plain',
        selectedExpr: 'isSelected',

         onItemClick: function (e) {...
```

I added *selectExpr:'isSelected'* option, and trying select my item use it:

```
  $scope.localArray[0].isSelected = true;
  $scope.localArray = $scope.localArray;
```

but it don't works, may be somebody have ideas how i can do it ? 
Thanks for Your answers!

Comment: What DevExtreme version do you use?

Comment: Sergey, i use a DevExtreme.Web.15.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DevExtreme v.15.2 tree view selection works only with the `showCheckBoxesMode: 'normal'` option.

```
$scope.treeViewOptions = {
    // tree view config...
    showCheckBoxesMode: 'normal'
};
```

The sample is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yQirTJ2u0998ud5NEIwH?p=preview).

But, if you want to apply a custom style to the item with the `isSelected` field, you can do it manually. Just use the [onItemRendered](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTreeView/Configuration/?version=15_2#onItemRendered) event and check if item is selected:

```
onItemRendered: function(args){
    if(args.itemData.isSelected) {
      args.itemElement.css("color", "green");
    }
}
```

[Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nnafHQNxDAkawIymoQN?p=preview).

Comment: oh, Thank you so much for your help! it's awesome.